# PHP escaping delimiter

Tags: php, string

I am using PHPs' `strtr` method to replace certain tokens/placeholders in a string. This works very well but now I'm trying to work out if all of my tokens were replaced.

The following example:

```
$trans = array(":hello" => "hi", ":hi" => "hello");
echo strtr(":hi all, I said :hello", $trans);
```

will output:

> hello all, I said hi

Both tokens were replaced successfully but how do I check this. I can't search the output for occurrences of my delimiter ':' since the output string could contain valid ':' in the data.

Is there a way that I can escape these delimiters before doing the replace, then do a count on the unescaped delimiters to see if there were any token left unreplaced, and then finally unescape the escaped delimiters before returning?

**NOTE:** I cannot use str_replace, this method needs to be used.

Comment: Why are you wanting to test this? Are you doubtful that a language built-in function works properly?

Comment: I need to make sure that all tokens have been replaced else throw an exception. str_replace returns me a total number of replacements it made but strtr does not, so now I need to do the replace and then try work out if everything was replaced. There is a chance that my $trans array is missing values that I need to replace in the string.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to make sure all of the keys in your `$trans` array were found in the string being transformed, not that whatever tokens were in the string were replaced. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `strtr` can help you here, it just replaces whatever it finds. What you seem to want is to figure out if there is a difference between the tokens in the array and in the string. For that, something like this should do:

```
preg_match_all('/:\w+/', $str, $matches);
if (array_diff($matches[0], array_keys($trans))) {
    // the string has tokens that aren't in $trans
}
```